# How to access property of $data?

Tags: knockout.js

I do `<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($data)'></pre>`

and i get 2 arrays with some data.

`<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($data.ResourceDetails)'></pre>`

does return me the properties of the specific array but if i do `$data.ResourceDetails.Name` it doesnt return anything.

Sample data from ResourceDetails

```
"Name": "298ff799-a4a6-4e2e-82d9-e8eb99e8e2d2",
"BranchID": 0,
"GroupUID": "37c0a2fc-caef-4bf3-adf0-9d187d9cf441",
"Capacity": 11,
"Duration": 60,
"ScheduleUID": "d62be6f8-b6ae-4806-9aef-832e073ee82c",
"Description": "Test",
"Active": 1,
"SortOrder": 0,
"CreatedBy": "System",
"CreatedOn": "2017-05-17T14:12:57.317",
"LastEditBy": "System",
"LastEditOn": "2017-05-17T14:12:57.317",
```

Whats wrong? Why i cannot success `Name` ?

`<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($data.ResourceDetails['Name'])'></pre>`

doesnt work aswell.

Comment: if `ResourceDetails` is an observable array, you need to access to one position in this array:  `ResourceDetails()[0]`.   More information:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: its an object coming from ajax call. Its not observable array.

Comment: You said that `$data.ResourceDetails.Name` don't return nothing.  And `$data` is Knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).  I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question, then.  :-(

Comment: Oh.. yeah my mistake. Its the way u said it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if `ResourceDetails` is an observable array, you need to access to one position in this array:

```
   ResourceDetails()[0]
```

More information: [Observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)